# How to reuse existing user data directory in Selenium ChromeDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I keep losing browser's session data when trying to recreate new `ChromeDriver` instance. I was able to logged-in into the GitHub website before calls `driver.Quit()`.

Surprisingly, recreating new driver instance with the same `user-data-dir` option makes me no longer logged in.

**Chrome options**

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument($"--user-data-dir={dir}"); // D:\repos\selenium-playground\bin\debug\browser\data
options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");
options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);

options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

**Chrome driver service**

```
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
```

**Creates ChromeDriver instance**
I use the same options & service when make authentication to the GitHub website.

```
var driver = ChromeDriver(service, options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://github.com");
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Most authentication involves cookies which require reauthorization each time a new page is loaded. How does logging in work the first time?

Comment: @JohnPeters Now this is weird, I pause the thread for 20 seconds before calls `driver.Quit`, it keeps me logged-in even with new driver instance.

Comment: Yes driver quit takes down all known state. You've  discoved that even new driver instances reuse cookies. Not surprising look at new instances as a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

I would try save cookies after first login, then reusing them on second try. And I don't think, that cookies are saved in this directory.